# How to detect focus on GtkSocket

Tags: linux, x11, gtk2, gdk

I have a window with a child window containing a socket. I need to detect when the keyboard focus changes from a widget in the parent window to a widget in the plug window.

I am getting no gdk events once the mouse enters the plug window until it leaves. I have tried `g_signal_connect` for `focus-in-event` on the child window & the plug window and I don't get any callback presumably because they themselves don't have keyboard focus.

Is there a way to be notified of this focus change?

Comment: "A child window containing a socket": do you mean a TCP or UDP socket? What does that have to do with the window itself?

Comment: Sorry, thought the title would give it away. I'm talking about a [GtkSocket](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkSocket.html) hosting a window not networking.